# django 2.2 "user-defined aggregate's 'finalize' method raised error"

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-2.2

//Django 2.2.2
//sqlite3

I am passing various statistical values ​​to Django template with Django Aggregate.

Avg, Count are working well. But Variance is not working and gives me OperationError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/project_app/views.py", line 116, in project_report
    print(subject)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 186, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 124, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/miguel/Outsourcings/myProject/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: user-defined aggregate's 'finalize' method raised error
[03/Jun/2019 20:41:24] "GET /project/report/7 HTTP/1.1" 500 224730
```

Variance is working when I wrote in models method.
But in views.py, not working.
I do not know what the difference between these two is..

views.py

```py
def project_report(request, pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(ProjectModel.objects, pk=pk)
    subject = project.subject_for_project.filter(status='on', party_status='join').annotate(feel_avg=Avg('datamodel__feeling'),
                 pain_avg=Avg('datamodel__pain'),
                 side_count=Count(Case(
                     When(datamodel__flag='side', then=1),
                     output_field=IntegerField(),
                 )),
                 # this part is not working
                 pain_variance=Variance('datamodel__pain')
                 )
    print(subject)
    context = {
        'project':project,
        'subject':subject,
    }
    return render(request, 'project/project_report.html, context)
```

models.py

```py
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=3, default='on')

class SubjectModel(models.Model):
    random_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subject_for_project')
    created_by_admin_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    party_status = models.CharField(choices=(('join', 'Join'), ('break', 'Break')), default='join', max_length=5)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=3, default='on')

class DataModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(SubjectModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drug = models.CharField(choices=DRUG, max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    side_effect = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    side_effect_more = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feeling = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=FEELING, blank=True, null=True)
    pain = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    flag = models.CharField(choices=FLAG, max_length=6)
```

According to the django 2.2 release notes, I read that the sqlite environment also supports variance, but if I cannot use it in the view, I want to find another way.
Thank you.

Comment: can you show the entire error trace?

Comment: how is `subject_for_project` defined? and how do you get to query on `datamodel`? It's not a field nor a related field on `SubjectModel`. Try some simple query in your console using `Variance` directly on the `DataModel`, e.g. `DataModel.objects.filter(...).values('drug').annotate(pain_variance=Variance('pain'))`

Comment: @dirkgroten
subject_for_project is related_name of SubjectModel's Foriegnkey.
Ok I'll try in my console then be back, thanks :)

Comment: @dirkgroten    I've just updated whole error messages..

Answer (score 0):

Despite using [version 2.2 of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#models), it seems that it still does not fully support Variance in sqlite database environment.

The error is not raised when it is created with a Method in the Class. However, when I create FBV in views.py and load it from the parent model, an error occurs.

I changed the local database to postgresql only, so the error is gone.